# Expected value of power of exponential order statistics

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

Finding the expected value of the $\gamma$:th power of the $k$:th standard exponential order statistic in a sample of $n$ implies evaluating the integral:

$E(X_{[k]}^{\gamma})=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\int_0^{\infty}{x^{\gamma}(1-e^{-x})^{k-1}e^{-x(n-k+1)}}dx$

... does anyone have a clue for me on how to do this..? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, for $\lambda>0$, we have

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\lambda}\,\text{d}x{}={}\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\,.
$$

So, by differentiating both sides w.r.t $\lambda$ (you can [differentiate under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)) "$\gamma$-times", observe that

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^{\gamma}e^{-x\lambda}\,\text{d}x{}={}\dfrac{\gamma!}{\lambda^{\gamma{}+{}1}}\,.
$$

Since your integral can be re-written as

$$
n{n-1\choose k-1}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{k-1}\left({k-1\choose r}(-)^r\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^{\gamma}e^{-x(r+n-k+1)}\,\text{d}x\right)\,,
$$

use the previous result to complete the integration.

Comment: Could you clarify the last step? Perhaps it should be trivial, but I don't see it...

Comment: @Olivia, in more detail, the integral in the question was rewritten by using the Binomial expansion of the term $\,\,\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^{k-1}$. In this new form, we see that the original integral in the question is a finite sum of integrals, each of which "look like" the integral in the result I stated by identifying
$$
\lambda{}={}r+n-k+1\,.
$$

So, we already know what the integration of each integral in the sum is: simply substitute  the answer in the result I quoted, replacing $\lambda$ with each $r+n-k+1$.

Comment: OK, now I see! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Olivia, You are welcome.